# unable to mock ResponseEntity for rest client

Tags: spring, mocking, rest-client

I am trying to mock rest client for junit test. here is my rest client line of code

```
ResponseEntity<MyClass[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(myurl, input, MyClass[].class);
```

On my junit i tried

```
MyClass[] classArr= new MyClass[myClassList.size()]; //here myClassList is list of MyClass
        classArr = myClassList.toArray(classArrclassArr);


        ResponseEntity<MyClass[]> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<MyClass[]>(classArr, HttpStatus.OK);       
        when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(String.class), any(InputParam.class), MyClass[].class)).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

But `responseEntity`  is returned null. Is there something i am doing wrong here

Comment: did you try with `any(MyClass[].class)`

Comment: I did. I get error-- Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyClass[] to Class<T>

Comment: try this `Matchers.<Class<MyClass[]>>any()`

Comment: That part i fixed but i am getting null back. I updated question. Could you please take a look.

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't compile. MyClass[] should be eq(MyClass[].class)

Comment: sorry. Updated my question